# Python 2.7 or 3.3 for learning Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am interested in learning Python but I don't know which version I should chose.  When I Googled, I got answers posted over a year ago. If I want to learn Django, which version will be useful and will get support?

Note that I know C, C++, Java and C#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django only has experimental support for Python 3, so you'll have to go with Python 2.7 for now.

Comment: @LevLevitsky: we are reaching a point that 3.3 is becoming a viable starting point for new projects, but I am reluctant to recommend it to newcomers to the language still. Most tutorial material still assumes a 2.x base, and there are many 3rd-party libraries still to port. Still, having Django support 3 is a major step.

Comment: @LevLevitsky i am not going to use django for next 1 year for productivity. I just need a starting point. So if i started with 3.2 or 3.3, with in an year there will be enough support for this versions Right?

Comment: @MartijnPieters what do you think about my previous comment?

Comment: @sujeesh As for the starting point, it's okay to start learning Python 2.7 now. When you are used to it, it shouldn't be too hard for you to grasp the main differences from Python 3.2 and the new stuff in 3.3. In a year, you'll be ready to develop in any of them, probably Python 3.3 will be well enough supported (imho).

Comment: @sujeesh: In a year's time, I'd expect the landscape to be different, yes. We are 3 years into the 5-year transition plan for the shift from 2.x to 3.x. That said, it's not hard to switch from 2 to 3.

Comment: @LevLevitsky so if i learn 2.7 in future will i feel much difficulty to swithch 3.X?

Comment: Nope. I agree with @Martijn, you'll be fine.

Comment: @LevLevitsky that's what i want.

Answer (score 1):

First, a short comparison is [It's Better than 2.7](https://us.pycon.org/2013/schedule/presentation/117/) and [When should Python 3.3 become the default](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2012-October/036008.html). However, remember that Python is in fact a script language and you can use C or C++ in doing modules with new capabilities.

Comment: "enter link description here" ? :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to start with python 2.7, it just more commonly used nowadays, and `django` is written in 2.7 AFAIK.

Apparently the answer you found still holds:

[Should we use python 2.6 or 2.7 or 3.x?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102999/should-we-use-python-2-6-or-2-7-or-3-x)

Answer (score 0):

If you already know several languages then learn both Python 2 and 3. The difference is small enough to allow many projects to support both versions using single (the same) source code.

For actual deployment you might prefer Python 2.7 if you need to use dependencies that are not ported to Python 3.